# Using either SQLAlchemy or DjanjoOrm, what is the most efficient method of retrieving and displaying a "comment" post and all of its "reply" posts?

Tags: python, django, sorting, sqlalchemy, django-orm

Take any typical comment system; every comment can have a reply and every reply can have more replies. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the methodology that could be used to most quickly/efficiently, and using python(3) and either flask/django ORM's:

- query all comments in commentDB where page_id == x
- cycle thru each result and build a list of lists where each entry
  gets added to it's parent_id list and after each entry re-sort
  the list based on time of entry/votes/etc

and then in the view/template:

- cycle through each list and format according

This seems like such an incredibly taxing operation to complete every time a new comment is added. I'm hoping to gather some insight on how this can be done "at scale". Is it better to run a separate query against every comment looking for other comments that has its id as the other's parent_id and build up/modify a redis list or something?

My database will be Postgres, in case that is helpful to know.

Comment: [django-threadedcomments](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-threadedcomments)

Comment: Are you looking into having an arbitrary depth, or will it be limited to say 3 levels of replies or such? Tree-like structures can be handled with [recursive common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: No level limit. Thank you for the link. I will look into seeing if either of the ORM's have any kind of built in support for this postgres feature.

Comment: SQLAlchemy supports [CTEs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.cte). I'm not sure if it'd be possible to form a query that'd populate a Python object tree directly, but it'd get you all the "ingredients" to it in a single query, at least. Btw this is also called an adjacency list relationship, and SQLA has a separate page for covering just that: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html.

Comment: Also since you're fetching comments based on a "page id" you don't even need fancy recursive CTEs, just good old sorting and then a bit of work Python side to form the tree. Order the results of the SQL query so that a parent always precedes its children and you can form the list of lists of lists ... in Python easily.

Comment: Or take the NoSQL route and store the comments of a page in a JSONB column or such.

Comment: drawbacks to the JSONB column approach?

Comment: @chrickso each time a comment is inserted/deleted/changed, the whole column must be rewritten, reindexed etc. I.e.: don't.

Comment: What if a user is removed? You'd have to go through all the JSONB values and update accordingly.